# .NET Core 2.2 How to protect against XSS properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am very unsure about how to protect against XSS in .NET Core 2.2.

I have looked around and it seems like its not being worked on and has been removed?

I have tried placing this in my Startup.cs

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Xss-Protection", "1");
            await next();
        });
```

But i get this error:

> ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
>   Key: X-Xss-Protection

What else can I do to prevent people from inserting items like this:

```
<script>alert(‘XSS’)</script>
```

into my forms?

Comment: The only way reliable way to prevent against XSS is to take steps to ensure that unvalidated inputs are not inserted into your page as HTML. One header isn't going to solve that for you, and in fact, most browsers are now deprecating the `X-Xss-Protection` header and Firefox has never supported it.

Comment: How do I do that? Is there a jquery function that can help with that?

Comment: You need to do that in server, and its not as easy as calling a function, in fact it involves not calling some functions like `Html.Raw` with user inputs among other things. Search about it and start reading .You can [start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways

1. [Set server-side security headers](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-security-headers/)
2. [Use the HtmlSanitizer Clean input from html tags](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer)
3. Using @html.encode in view To block execution of JavaScript code snippets

You need to do one of these three ways I suggest using a second solution to virtually clear entries from tags